# Will there be a problem with the [ios] tag?

Tags: tagging, tags

So people are already using [ios] to talk about the iPhone/iPad operating system, which makes sense. However, as this is a security site, I imagine some people will want to talk about IOS, the Cisco router environment. Now this is Cisco's silly fault for licensing their trademarks to Apple (iPhone was one of theirs too), but what should we do about it? I think that as there aren't any IOS questions yet, we can define [cisco-ios] to be the tag for IOS and leave [ios] for iOS. But this is all very confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this makes sense on numbers - Apple iOS is likely to be queried much more (not least as Cisco have a pretty good knowledge base themselves, so most folks would go there first).

Anyway, worst case if someone posts up a Cisco IOS question, one of us is likely to spot it and be able to retag to [cisco-ios]

If we find many questions on both sides, we can always come back and revisit the decision.

Comment: I think that makes sense... But should we preemptively change the other to [apple-ios] too?

Comment: I dont think so, partly from intellectual laziness, but I'm throwing it out there... :)

Comment: @AviD: I think not. If most questions are going to be Apple iOS (and so far, they are) then there's no point burdening people with remembering that we don't have an iOS tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that we put both tags into strict use now, `apple-ios` and `cisco-ios`.  I imagine it will be a bit more difficult to do it later on, if we decide it's become necessary when there are many more questions on the topics.

Comment: dont worry too much about it, moderators have secret tools to help with renaming tags... :)

Comment: @AviD And those will help distinguish between which `ios` tags need renaming to `apple-ios` and which to `cisco-ios` on a mass scale?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if someone with the edit tag-wikis ability could also fill in the tag wikis for the ios entries with something appropriate.  For those that know they're there, they can help eliminate confusion.  You could also have an 'apple-ios' tag synonym for 'ios' if that is determined to be the correct mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw another suggestion in here.  For Apple/Cisco iOS/IOS questions, use both applicable tags.  My question about [Cisco IOS config file auditing](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1982/953) has both the [cisco](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco) and [ios](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) tags.

Comment: I fixed it by retagging your question `cisco-ios` to match the accepted answer ;)